# Redirecting based on TLD extentions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ive been looking around Google for the answer but i cant seem to find it.
Im trying to make a redirect based on the top level domain extention

For example

I have many domains that are aimed for the same server.

```
www.domainA.com
www.domainB.net
www.domainC.nl
www.domainC.com
```

Now the site has 2 languages.
English -- domain.com/en
Dutch -- domain.com/nl

I want to make a htaccess redirect that looks at the top level domain extention and redirect it to the language :

```
.nl  -> domain.nl/nl
.com -> domain.com/en
.net -> domain.net/en
```

But everywhere i look i see people useing the full domain name as a reconizer for the redirect

ive tryed to change the full domain examples to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^\.nl          [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         /nl          [L,R=301]
```

However this doesnt work. Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.%2/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The domain needs to be variable aswell.. so if i come in on domainC.com i want to keep domainC.com/en and domainC.nl/nl and domainB.com/en ect... The Domain could have more names

Comment: I tryed your code and it keeps redirecting from .nl to .com, i removed the .com in your last line and also that didn't help.

Comment: Did you not write: `.nl  -> domain.com/nl` in your question?